# I need to restrict a composable type on composable parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Edited without images.

My team and I are implementing a Design System, it works quite well already, and the usage of it looks like this : CardComponent.Default() or CardComponent.Alternative().

A CardComponent can use other components.
In a CardComponent, I'm going to pass a @Composable parameter, named note :

```
object CardComponent {

    @Composable
    fun Default(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        note: @Composable () -> Unit,
    ) {
        // Do stuff with it
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that in the usage, when I call CardComponent.Default :

```
CardComponent.Default(
    modifier = Modifier,
    note = {
        NoteComponent.Default()
    }
)
```

Nothing is protecting the user (developer) from using it with another component :

```
CardComponent.Default(
    modifier = Modifier,
    note = {
        PillComponent.Default()
    }
)
```

What would you do to prevent the user from abusing this AND keep the simple usage we currently have ? Keep in mind that I only showed a Default @Composable, but there are at least 2 different @Composables in each object.

We could just trust them, or we could find a simple solution, but it might - will - happen that someone makes a mistake or that the UI says "trust me bro, just put a Pill in it, it will work".

Comment: Please post code as text, not images

Comment: Sorry, just edited my message

Comment: Have the design system in its own module, and have the API exposed by that module reflect the valid uses. In this case, `NoteComponent` and `CardComponent` would be `internal` to that module, and something like `NoteCardComponent` would be the public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the type system is the correct way to try and prevent users from doing things like this.

Nothing in the Compose core libraries prevents you from nesting many `Surface`s or adding a lot of UI inside a `TextField`. Then why doesn't anyone do it? Well, because it looks bad. And the same applies here: Presumably, your Cards will add some borders and other decorations, and nesting them won't look good. That should be enough to deter the developer from using it beyond a single attempt.

Comment: You make a very good point about users not doing it cause it doesn't look good.